# How to insert two columns of two tables into one column of other table

Tags: sql, join

Hi I am having trouble joining 3 tables

```
table1(id1,name_1)

Table2(id2,top,name_2,fk_id1)

table3(id3,top,name_3,fk_id1)
```

and as a result i want o have:

```
tableResult(id1,name_1,top,name_2,name_3)
```

ps: `top` contain data from `table2.top` and `table3.top`

Comment: Please, clarify - what exactly problem do you have? Your desired output can be result of straight joins to table2 and table3, but what do you need to do with `top` columns of these tables? What is data types of that column? In what manner that data should be combined? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev i want the output to be the result of joining table1, table2 and table 3, top is two different column in the two tables that i want to put in one column in the output table

Comment: @Hchliyah: No, we are talking of the top fields. Say you have a record in table2 with top = 2 and a record in table3 with top = 3, then what shall your result row contain; top = 2 or top = 3 or top = '23' or top = 5 or what else? Tell us the rule what to put in the top result field.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner top will have two rows 2 and 3

Comment: @Hchliyah It is still not clear what final result should be. What about example?

Comment: @Hchliyah: That makes no sense. You are showing the result you want to get, which is `id1,name_1,top,name_2,name_3`. So each row in your results has `id1` and `name_1` and `top` and `name_2` and `name_3`. So which `top` to show in a row? The one from table2? The one from table3? The sum of the two? What else? As Andy Korneyev said two times now: show an example!

Comment: Or do you mean two **columns**?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am assuming your result needs to look like:

```
1. ID1, Name1, Top (from table 2), Name2, Name3
2. ID1, Name1, Top (from table 3), Name2, Name3
```

For Example:

> ```
> 1. 514, Bill, 2, Sam, Jill
> 2. 514, Bill, 3, Sam, Jill
> 3. 515, Jack, 5, Bob, Tom
> 4. 515, Jack, 6, Bom, Tom
> ```

I think you need to use a `UNION ALL` operator.

```
SELECT A.ID_1, A.Name_1, B.Top, B.Name_2, C.Name_3
FROM Table1 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.Id_1 = B.Id_1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 AS C
     ON A.ID_1 = C.ID_1
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID_1, A.Name_1, C.Top, B.Name_2, C.Name_3 --Notice that this grabs Top from Table 3
FROM Table1 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.Id_1 = B.Id_1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 AS C
     ON A.ID_1 = C.ID_1
```

I'm not certain on your rules, so you may need to use a different join than LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want join, the query below should do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.fk_id1 = a.id1
JOIN table3 c ON c.fk_id1 = a.id1
```